# PHP slow reading from DB

Tags: php, sql-server, performance

I did some benchmarking around the time it takes to read from our DB. This was just connect to the DB, read some records into memory, and then instantiate an object/struct from them.

I was blown away by how long it takes PHP even compared to Python. I'd consider them at the same level in terms of language abstraction and expected similar levels of performance. Does anyone have any idea why this takes so long?

This was with PHP8.0 NTS and the MSSQL driver from Microsoft via PDO.

For some clarification, each benchmark was ran 5 times. The number of records to read into memory is the number in the left side of the tuple that contains the language name.

|  | ('timeElapsedInSeconds', 'count') | ('timeElapsedInSeconds', 'mean') | ('timeElapsedInSeconds', 'std') | ('timeElapsedInSeconds', 'min') | ('timeElapsedInSeconds', '25%') | ('timeElapsedInSeconds', '50%') | ('timeElapsedInSeconds', '75%') | ('timeElapsedInSeconds', 'max') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (1000, 'F#') | 5 | 1.8476 | 0.195108 | 1.536 | 1.82 | 1.862 | 1.983 | 2.037 |
| (1000, 'Go') | 5 | 1.18728 | 0.190045 | 1.07071 | 1.08324 | 1.09012 | 1.17277 | 1.51955 |
| (1000, 'PHP') | 5 | 3.76034 | 1.3344 | 2.89244 | 2.94234 | 2.94956 | 4.02734 | 5.99001 |
| (1000, 'Python') | 5 | 1.41568 | 0.0171894 | 1.40233 | 1.40883 | 1.4095 | 1.41198 | 1.44576 |
| (10000, 'F#') | 5 | 2.9868 | 0.284031 | 2.628 | 2.737 | 3.134 | 3.176 | 3.259 |
| (10000, 'Go') | 5 | 2.45832 | 0.787024 | 1.68207 | 1.77937 | 2.35108 | 2.93793 | 3.54117 |
| (10000, 'PHP') | 5 | 29.7064 | 4.62237 | 26.3522 | 26.7064 | 27.8346 | 30.086 | 37.5528 |
| (10000, 'Python') | 5 | 3.24596 | 0.635794 | 2.82961 | 2.91629 | 2.9419 | 3.18317 | 4.35884 |
| (100000, 'F#') | 5 | 21.62 | 5.53258 | 16.291 | 17.568 | 19.088 | 27.223 | 27.93 |
| (100000, 'Go') | 5 | 15.9468 | 5.15966 | 10.0845 | 11.4231 | 17.3517 | 18.2748 | 22.5999 |
| (100000, 'PHP') | 5 | 264.245 | 4.3104 | 258.296 | 263.512 | 263.916 | 265.137 | 270.367 |
| (100000, 'Python') | 5 | 24.3966 | 3.2381 | 20.6309 | 22.02 | 25.0827 | 25.2866 | 28.9628 |

```
<?php 

require "../vendor/autoload.php";

ini_set("memory_limit", -1);

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv -> load();

class Sales {
    public $field1;
    public $field2;
    public $field3;
    public $field4;
    public $field5;
    public $field6;
    public $field7;
    public $field8;
    public $field9;
    public $field10;
    public $field11;
    public $field12;
    public $field13;
    public $field14;
    public $field15;
    public $field16;
    public $field17;
    public $field18;
    public $field19;
    public $field20;
    public $field21;
    public $field22;
    public $field23;
    public $field24;
    public $field25;
    public $field26;
    public $field27;
    public $field28;
    public $field29;
    public $field30;
    public $field31;
    public $field32;
    public $field33;
    public $field34;
    public $field35;
    public $field36;
    public $field37;
    public $field38;
    public $field39;
    public $field40;
    public $field41;
    public $field42;
    public $field43;
    public $field44;
    public $field45;
    public $field46;
    public $field47;
    public $field48;
    public $field49;
    public $field50;
    public $field51;
    public $field52;
    public $field53;
    public $field54;
    public $field55;
    public $field56;
    public $field57;
    public $field58;
    public $field59;
    public $field60;
    public $field61;
    public $field62;
}
const rows = 100000;
const query = "select top " . rows . " * from table";
$user = $_ENV["user"];
$password = $_ENV["password"];
$host = $_ENV["host"];
$db = $_ENV["database"];

$start = microtime(true);
$db = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$host;Database=$db;", $user, $password );
$results = $db -> query( query ) -> fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
$data = [];
foreach( $results as $result ) {
    $obj = new Sales();
    $obj -> field1 = $result[ "field1" ];
    $obj -> field2 = $result[ "field2" ];
    $obj -> field3 = $result[ "field3" ];
    $obj -> field4 = $result[ "field4" ];
    $obj -> field5 = $result[ "field5" ];
    $obj -> field6 = $result[ "field6" ];
    $obj -> field7 = $result[ "field7" ];
    $obj -> field8 = $result[ "field8" ];
    $obj -> field9 = $result[ "field9" ];
    $obj -> field10 = $result[ "field10" ];
    $obj -> field11 = $result[ "field11" ];
    $obj -> field12 = $result[ "field12" ];
    $obj -> field13 = $result[ "field13" ];
    $obj -> field14 = $result[ "field14" ];
    $obj -> field15 = $result[ "field15" ];
    $obj -> field16 = $result[ "field16" ];
    $obj -> field17 = $result[ "field17" ];
    $obj -> field18 = $result[ "field18" ];
    $obj -> field19 = $result[ "field19" ];
    $obj -> field20 = $result[ "field20" ];
    $obj -> field21 = $result[ "field21" ];
    $obj -> field22 = $result[ "field22" ];
    $obj -> field23 = $result[ "field23" ];
    $obj -> field24 = $result[ "field24" ];
    $obj -> field25 = $result[ "field25" ];
    $obj -> field26 = $result[ "field26" ];
    $obj -> field27 = $result[ "field27" ];
    $obj -> field28 = $result[ "field28" ];
    $obj -> field29 = $result[ "field29" ];
    $obj -> field30 = $result[ "field30" ];
    $obj -> field31 = $result[ "field31" ];
    $obj -> field32 = $result[ "field32" ];
    $obj -> field33 = $result[ "field33" ];
    $obj -> field34 = $result[ "field34" ];
    $obj -> field35 = $result[ "field35" ];
    $obj -> field36 = $result[ "field36" ];
    $obj -> field37 = $result[ "field37" ];
    $obj -> field38 = $result[ "field38" ];
    $obj -> field39 = $result[ "field39" ];
    $obj -> field40 = $result[ "field40" ];
    $obj -> field41 = $result[ "field41" ];
    $obj -> field42 = $result[ "field42" ];
    $obj -> field43 = $result[ "field43" ];
    $obj -> field44 = $result[ "field44" ];
    $obj -> field45 = $result[ "field45" ];
    $obj -> field46 = $result[ "field46" ];
    $obj -> field47 = $result[ "field47" ];
    $obj -> field48 = $result[ "field48" ];
    $obj -> field49 = $result[ "field49" ];
    $obj -> field50 = $result[ "field50" ];
    $obj -> field51 = $result[ "field51" ];
    $obj -> field52 = $result[ "field52" ];
    $obj -> field53 = $result[ "field53" ];
    $obj -> field54 = $result[ "field54" ];
    $obj -> field55 = $result[ "field55" ];
    $obj -> field56 = $result[ "field56" ];
    $obj -> field57 = $result[ "field57" ];
    $obj -> field58 = $result[ "field58" ];
    $obj -> field59 = $result[ "field59" ];
    $obj -> field60 = $result[ "field60" ];
    $obj -> field61 = $result[ "field61" ];
    $obj -> field62 = $result[ "field62" ];
    $data[] = $obj;
}

$stop = microtime(true);

file_put_contents("./../../benchmarks.txt", "PHP, " . rows . ", " . ( $stop - $start ) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

```py
import pyodbc
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import time

class Sales: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.field1 = None
        self.field2 = None
        self.field3 = None
        self.field4 = None
        self.field5 = None
        self.field6 = None
        self.field7 = None
        self.field8 = None
        self.field9 = None
        self.field10 = None
        self.field11 = None
        self.field12 = None
        self.field13 = None
        self.field14 = None
        self.field15 = None
        self.field16 = None
        self.field17 = None
        self.field18 = None
        self.field19 = None
        self.field20 = None
        self.field21 = None
        self.field22 = None
        self.field23 = None
        self.field24 = None
        self.field25 = None
        self.field26 = None
        self.field27 = None
        self.field28 = None
        self.field29 = None
        self.field30 = None
        self.field31 = None
        self.field32 = None
        self.field33 = None
        self.field34 = None
        self.field35 = None
        self.field36 = None
        self.field37 = None
        self.field38 = None
        self.field39 = None
        self.field40 = None
        self.field41 = None
        self.field42 = None
        self.field43 = None
        self.field44 = None
        self.field45 = None
        self.field46 = None
        self.field47 = None
        self.field48 = None
        self.field49 = None
        self.field50 = None
        self.field51 = None
        self.field52 = None
        self.field53 = None
        self.field54 = None
        self.field55 = None
        self.field56 = None
        self.field57 = None
        self.field58 = None
        self.field59 = None
        self.field60 = None
        self.field61 = None
        self.field62 = None


def main() -> None:
    load_dotenv()
    rows = 100000
    query = f"select top {rows} * from table"
    start = time.time()
    connection = pyodbc.connect( os.environ["connection_string"] )    
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    data = []
    for row in result:
        obj = Sales()
        obj.field1 = row[ 0 ]
        obj.field2 = row[ 1 ]
        obj.field3 = row[ 2 ]
        obj.field4 = row[ 3 ]
        obj.field5 = row[ 4 ]
        obj.field6 = row[ 5 ]
        obj.field7 = row[ 6 ]
        obj.field8 = row[ 7 ]
        obj.field9 = row[ 8 ]
        obj.field10 = row[ 9 ]
        obj.field11 = row[ 10 ]
        obj.field12 = row[ 11 ]
        obj.field13 = row[ 12 ]
        obj.field14 = row[ 13 ]
        obj.field15 = row[ 14 ]
        obj.field16 = row[ 15 ]
        obj.field17 = row[ 16 ]
        obj.field18 = row[ 17 ]
        obj.field19 = row[ 18 ]
        obj.field20 = row[ 19 ]
        obj.field21 = row[ 20 ]
        obj.field22 = row[ 21 ]
        obj.field23 = row[ 22 ]
        obj.field24 = row[ 23 ]
        obj.field25 = row[ 24 ]
        obj.field26 = row[ 25 ]
        obj.field27 = row[ 26 ]
        obj.field28 = row[ 27 ]
        obj.field29 = row[ 28 ]
        obj.field30 = row[ 29 ]
        obj.field31 = row[ 30 ]
        obj.field32 = row[ 31 ]
        obj.field33 = row[ 32 ]
        obj.field34 = row[ 33 ]
        obj.field35 = row[ 34 ]
        obj.field36 = row[ 35 ]
        obj.field37 = row[ 36 ]
        obj.field38 = row[ 37 ]
        obj.field39 = row[ 38 ]
        obj.field40 = row[ 39 ]
        obj.field41 = row[ 40 ]
        obj.field42 = row[ 41 ]
        obj.field43 = row[ 42 ]
        obj.field44 = row[ 43 ]
        obj.field45 = row[ 44 ]
        obj.field46 = row[ 45 ]
        obj.field47 = row[ 46 ]
        obj.field48 = row[ 47 ]
        obj.field49 = row[ 48 ]
        obj.field50 = row[ 49 ]
        obj.field51 = row[ 50 ]
        obj.field52 = row[ 51 ]
        obj.field53 = row[ 52 ]
        obj.field54 = row[ 53 ]
        obj.field55 = row[ 54 ]
        obj.field56 = row[ 55 ]
        obj.field57 = row[ 56 ]
        obj.field58 = row[ 57 ]
        obj.field59 = row[ 58 ]
        obj.field60 = row[ 59 ]
        obj.field61 = row[ 60 ]
        obj.field62 = row[ 61 ]
        data.append( obj )
    stop = time.time()

    with open("./../benchmarks.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(f"Python, {rows}, {(stop - start):0.10f}\n")
        f.flush()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Comment: You could try the ODBC driver for MS-SQL. You also forgot to mention what your system looks like. Is it Windows? Is the DB-server on the same machine?

Comment: I am on windows and the db is on a separate machine.

Comment: Based on your results, we can clearly see that the difference between Python and PHP grows as you increase the row count. This gives the hint that your foreach loop has some performance issue. Most probably in fetching the results and converting to the object. We will need to further profile the code to see where it is taking time.

Comment: I've attached the python implementation. First thing that comes to mind is access methods into the row. PHP is by string vs python by positional. However, could that cause THAT much of an impact on performance?